# Не работает lowriter --convert-to pdf на сервере

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сервер, libre-office

Итак, я написал свое веб-приложение конвертер файлов word в pdf.
Однако все утыкается в работу libreoffice, он просто отказывается конвертировать.
Команда

```
lowriter --convert-to pdf test.docx
```

не работает на сервере, хотя на моем компьютере все работает идеально.
На сервере установлена ubuntu 22.04, версия LibreOffice 7.3.7.2 30(Build:2), точно так же как и на моем компьютере.
При запуске команды через команду `strace` выдается следующий лог:
[Страница с текстом лога](https://ermishovni.ru/information/log)

Большинство решений предложенных в интернете по типу убить все процессы офиса и использовать команды soffice я попробовал и они не помогли.

Есть ли решение данной проблемы или хотя бы обходной путь в качестве использования запуска lowriter из докер контейнера (при втором варианте желательно пояснить как).
Заранее благодарствую!

Answer (score 0):

`--headless`     добавить надо.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30465397/2101808 вроде подробный разбор вашей задачи

Comment: Я уже видел эти решения и они не помогли.
Кроме того, --headless с --convert-to использовать не нужно. --convert-to уже работает в режиме headless mode.

Comment: Отличие десктопного запуска и запуска в сервере в наличии доступа к видео и дисплею.

Comment: Поэтому надо копать в этом направлении сначала

Comment: я бы и рад, но я уже все перерыл, на что хватает мозгов.